# Why programm does not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates

created a template class for the array. Then I created constructors and destructors, overloaded the input and output operators.

```
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

template <typename T> class myArray;
template< typename T> ostream& operator <<(ostream &, const myArray <T> &);
template< typename T> istream& operator >> (istream &, const myArray<T> &);

template <typename T> class myArray
{
private:
T**mas; 
int line, 
    column;
friend istream& operator >> <T>(istream &, const myArray &);
friend ostream& operator << <T>(ostream &, const myArray &);

public:
myArray() : mas (0), line ( 0) column (0) {} 
myArray(int n, int m);
myArray(const myArray &masToCopy);
~myArray() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<line; i++)
    {
        delete[](mas[i]);
    }
    delete[](mas);
}
};
 template <typename T> myArray <T>::myArray(int n ,int m ) 
{
mas = new T*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mas[i] = new T[m];
}
}
template <typename T> myArray <T>:: myArray(const myArray &masToCopy)
{
line = masToCopy.line;
column = masToCopy.column;

mas = new T*[line];  
for (int i = 0; i <line; i++)
    mas[i] = new T[column];

for (int i = 0; i<line; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        mas[i][j] = masToCopy.mas[i][j];
}

template< typename T> istream& operator >> (istream &in, const myArray<T> &el) 
{
for (int i = 0; i < el.line; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < el.column; j++)
    {
        in >> el.mas[i][j];

    }
}
return in;
}

template< typename T> ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const myArray<T> &el) 
{
for (int i = 0; i < el.line; i++)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < el.column; j++)
    {
        out << el.mas[i][j];
        cout << " ";
    }
}
return out;
}
```

When I try to use my class the program does not allow to enter an array and then does not show it. Instead it mmediately writes "To continue, press any key"

```
using std:: cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
myArray<int> intArray1(2,2);
cin >> intArray1;
cout << intArray1;
return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could save us some time and tell us which symbol it cannot find.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but when you allocate memory in the constructors, shouldn't you be using `T` instead of `int` as the type? I.e. `mas[i] = new T[m];` instead of `mas[i] = new int[m]`?

Comment: @nwp I added a screenshot

Comment: please provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code does not compile.

Comment: As for your problem, you seem to have made a copy-paste error. Both the input and output operator takes an `istream` as its first argument. Your output operator is flawed in other ways as well, using `cout` instead of the supposedly output stream. By the way, that function shouldn't have made it past the compiler to the linker.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I corrected this mistake. But my program still does not allow to enter an array and then does not show it. Instead it mmediately writes "To continue, press any key"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the fact that it did make it past the compiler could imply that is was never instantiated in the first place. Interesting

Comment: @Ap31 not really. that can happen with template classes.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius can you elaborate? I'm not sure I get what you mean

Comment: templated functions are not 'generated' until they are referenced. In this case `friend ostream& operator << <T>(ostream &, const myArray &);` does not correctly reference to `template< typename T> ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const myArray<T> &el)`. Thus the compiler doesn't ever evaluate the implementation internals of the function: it thinks "don't compile unused functions". Else e.g. `cout << "\n";` would also have given an compiler error, as `cout` is not known there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's your problem:

```
template< typename T> ostream& operator << (istream &in, const myArray<T> &el)
```

should be

```
template< typename T> ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const myArray<T> &el)
```

copy-paste error...
edit: so, I see `Some programmer dude` said this in the comments while I was writing this answer. sorry bout that.

edit 2:
remove this, as it is not required

```
template <typename T> class myArray;
template< typename T> ostream& operator <<(ostream &, const myArray <T> &);
template< typename T> istream& operator >> (istream &, const myArray<T> &);
```

Then more errors:

```
friend istream& operator >> <T>(istream &, const myArray &);
```

should be:

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream &, const myArray &)
{
    [inlined code]
}
```

And next:

```
mas = new int*[line];
for (int i = 0; i <line; i++)
    mas[i] = new int[column];
```

should be

```
mas = new T*[line];
for (int i = 0; i <line; i++)
    mas[i] = new T[column];
```

end then

```
myArray<T>::myArray(int n, int m)
{
```

should be:

```
myArray<T>::myArray(int n, int m)
    : line(n)
    , column(m)
{
```

etc etc. there are just *so* many errors in the code.

Comment: I corrected this mistake. But my program still does not allow to enter an array and then does not show it. Instead it mmediately writes "To continue, press any key"

Comment: @choko edited. please learn to use a debugger. There are just so many errors in your code.